# How to query smart goals from the Google analytics export in Bigquery?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-analytics-api

In my GA account, I have a smart goal set up. I have got the GA raw data export in BQ. I have already written a query to get goals which are either destination or event-based. Now I want to query the [smart goal](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6153083?hl=en). As the smart goal does not have any specific definition, I need help with how we can query this data. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a segment on GA for smart goals.

- Advanced > Conditions > Filter sessions to include smart goal completes per session > 0

Add the segment on BQ and export.

Comment: Thanks, @Raymond! could you please tell how to get the GA segment into BQ?, I have created a segment in GA.

Comment: @Yog Go to segment parameter in query explorer and search the new segment you created. It should show up and the data here should match GA when you filter your segment.